# Основы человеко-понятных урлов

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, apache-modules, чпу

Имеется Apache, PHP и сабж. Хочу сделать на своем сайте человеко-понятные урлы (Friendly URL). Вычитал про `mod_rewrite` и `FilesMatch`. Подскажите, что лучше выбрать? Что на эту тему почитать? М.б. кто занимался уже, знает, киньте образец? Хочу сделать быстро, практично и безопасно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю такую схему:
Используй mod_rewrite и в htaccess напиши следующее (чтобы потом для каждого нового окна не дописывать):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/?_p=$0 [L]
```

Ты можешь убрать следующие строки:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Они нужны для того, чтобы подхватился скрипт во вложенных файлах (предположим ты в папке /forum/ разместил форум. Без этих строк он не запустится (вернее без последней)).

Как я делаю теперь обработку в скрипте (учитываю что параметры разделяются слешем и первый параметр-это страница, которую надо вывести):

```
define('HTACCESS_GET_PATH_URL','_p');
define('DEFAULT_PAGE_CODE','main');
...
function _get(){
    if(isset($_GET[HTACCESS_GET_PATH_URL]))
        return explode('/',$_GET[HTACCESS_GET_PATH_URL]);
return array(DEFAULT_PAGE_CODE);
}
...
Далее использую массив так:
$argv=_get();
$pageCode=basename(array_shift($argv));
Далее у меня логика вызова страницы (создание класса), где я передаю этот массив как параметр.
Предположим мне надо запросить такую страницу /view/123/
в класс, как ты уже понял, попадает в 0 элементе 123. Вытаскиваю я его так:
if(!$id=array_shift($this->argv)){
    ... Не указан id и вывод об ошибке
}
... work...
```

Надеюсь тебе пригодится. Начинал как ты, парился каждый раз писать чпу для каждой страницы, потом надоело, и сделал так. Идея не моя, но доточенная под себя!

Что касается FileMatch - если я не ошибаюсь, то это совсем не к пу относится а к настройкам приватности файлов сервера, как пример (скрываю исходники):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Где его писать?: на твое усморение и на смотря что тебе доступно: конфиг апача, тогда можешь там написать. Ну а сесли арендуешь у провайдера, то htaccess (он и предназначен для этого).

Работать будет при включенной поддержке mod_rewrite у провайдера.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня уже есть успехи!